# Intel HD graphics on HP Stream 13 only working with nomodeset

Tags: graphics, hp, brightness, intel, nomodeset

Already installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 alpha. All these versions just boot up to a blank white screen with some fuzzy colored lines where I can't do anything.

It works with nomodeset or i915.modeset=0, but obviously the graphics performance is horrible. I could live with that, but it would be very nice to adjust the screen brightness somehow. I already tried setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=(some value..) but it doesn't do a thing.

Is there anything else I could try to get the graphics working properly or at least adjust the screen brightness?

lspci:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)`

lshw:

```
Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 21
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff
```